# VMware still updates its modules even when i disable updates?

Tags: linux, vmware, vmware-workstation

I have explicitly disabled updates in setting (preferences -> updates)

but still from time to time, VMware updates its component and asks for me to type the admin password to update them ( Im using linux)

what part of not wanting to update does it not understand? how can i completely disable the updates?

Comment: Which component is updated?

Comment: and where did you disable it? what VMware product are you talking about?

Comment: @Zina   i disabled it in VMware setting. VMware workstation. when i click on it it asks for installling newly updated modules.

Comment: would you be so kind and edit your post with a screenshot of "Preferences / Updates" and the config file entries with the settings / values having "download" & "update" in the name. would you also provide the version of WS running and what components are offered to be updated.